# Python text to xml converting solutions

Tags: python, xml, regex, text

Hi guys I have written some code in python and its look like :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import re

output = open('epg.xml','w')
n = 0
print >> output, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>'+'\t'
print >> output, '<data>'

with open('epg_slo_utf_xml.txt','r') as txt:
    for line in txt:
        if re.search('Program', line) !=None:           
            n =n + 1
            e ='<program name=SLO>'+line+'</program>'

        if re.search('Start', line) !=None:
            n = n + 1
            f ='<start>'+line+'</start>'

            if re.search('duration', line) !=None:
                n = n + 1
                g ='<duration>'+line+'<duration>'

            wo = e + f              
            print >> output, wo

    print >> output , '</data>
```

But when I want to add code for discovering Duration from my text file, like this:

```
if re.search('duration', line) !=None:
    n = n + 1
    g ='<duration>'+line+'<duration>'
```

And when I run script I get this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./epg_transform.py", line 25, in <module>
    wo = e + f + g 
NameError: name 'g' is not defined
```

My text file looks like this :

```
Program 5   
            Start   2013-09-12 05:30:00 
            Duration   06:15:00 
                  Title INFOCANALE   
        Program 6   
            Start   2013-09-12 06:40:00 
            Duration   00:50:00 
                  Title Vihar   
        Program 9   
            Start   2013-09-12 06:45:00 
            Duration   00:29:00 
                  Title TV prodaja   

        Program 7   
        Program 6   
        Program 13   
            Start   2013-09-12 06:20:00 
            Duration   00:50:00 
                  Title Kursadžije
```

I think that problem is when re.search finds Program but without other elements in text file or maybe Program with multiplay start, duration, title like:

```
Program 7   
           Start   2013-09-16 00:10:00 
           Duration   02:00:00 
                 Title Love TV   
           Start   2013-09-16 02:10:00 
           Duration   01:50:00 
                 Title Nočna ptica
```

Thanks, for reading and can you help me with this problem?

Comment: I've tried to fix your indentation, don't know if it's correct now though. If it is, then the innermost `if` will never evaluate to `true` as a line that contains `Start` never contains `Duration`, thus `g` is never defined. With input data like this, I'd split the lines into the `Program` blocks and then iterate over the resulting blocks with a nested loop iterating over the lines of each block; then you can gather data in the inner loop and write it in the outer one, leading to a much clearer structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your code I would say, its just a typo - you are looking for `'duration'`, but the file only holds `'Duration'`, with a capital D. Thus, g is never set. You can avoid this behavior by initializing your variables at the beginning by setting them to an empty string.
On a side note, for such an easy task like checking for a word within a line you do not need `re`, try the - I guess - more "pythonic" way:

```
if 'Duration' in line:
    #do something
```